# Stuck when install scipy in CentOS

Tags: python, centos, scipy

Environment is Python 3.5 and CentOS 7.0 in VPS (XEN).
I use IUS repository for CentOS7 to install Python 3.5 and corresponding devel, setuptools packages.
Then upgrade pip3.5 itself by

```
sudo pip3.5 install upgrade pip
```

Numpy and Matplotlib can be installed by pip 3.5 without any problem.

```
sudo pip3.5 install numpy
sudo pip3.5 install matplotlib
```

But when I try to install scipy, it got stuck at the step running setup.py like forever. Only way to get rid of this is Ctrl+C. Tried several times, even reinstall CentOS and compile Python3.5 from source code. Always the same issue happens.

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.17.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... \
```

Could someone help me out please?

---

update (Feb 9th 2016):
A 1.5GB swapfile is created manually, which is none originally. Then after about 2 hours waiting, it is finally installed. I guess the relatively low performance of server leads to this problem.

Comment: What is it actually doing while stuck? Try using `ps aux -Hw` and/or `strace`.

Comment: @kichik Thanks for the reply. I executed pip command above with strace. It seems it stuck during compiling sth. The last few lines are as follows: read(5, "g++: scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bs"..., 4096) = 38
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1454527314, 784370895}) = 0
write(1, "\10 \10\\", \)                = 4
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1454527314, 784573496}) = 0
read(5, "In file included from /usr/lib64"..., 4096) = 606
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1454527314, 834263015}) = 0
... (similar output with clock_gettime above)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1454527314, 834687661}) = 0
read(5,

Comment: Try getting the exact command with `ps aux -Hww` and run it again while this is stuck. It might give you some valuable information.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried that. It stuck in the similar place. The major difference between two ps commands is that a process related to compiling appears. The last command it was executing is that: `root     22843  0.0  3.3 151936 33952 pts/0    S+   04:11   0:00                           as -I scipy/sparse/sparsetools -I /usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I /usr/include/python3.5m --64 -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.o`. Also I checked memory. Only about 57MB (free) is left and total amount is 1GB. Could out of memory be the problem?

Comment: Maybe. Have you tried upgrading `g++` and/or `as`? Maybe this is a known issue that has been fixed.

Comment: I just upgraded gcc, g++ and as to the latest version in Fedora 23 and repeat the installation. It still doesn't work. I watched the memory usage. Before the final AS command, memory usage is alright, which is about half free. Then it ate most of memory.

Comment: How big is the file it's compiling? Did you try giving your VM more RAM?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. After some different attempts, it eventually works. I manually created 1.5GB swapfile, which it's none originally in the server. Then when it stuck, I waited for about two hours, scipy is installed successfully. It's unbelievable that the compilation costs so much time. On my MacBook Pro, pip3.5 only needs a few minutes to finish scipy installation. Your patience and help are highly appreciated!